# Flexigrid loading data from local json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I am trying to fill flexigrid table from local created json object,
using this code:

```
var rows = new Array();
rows.push({cell: [1, 2, 3] });
rows.push({cell: [11, 22, 33] });
rows.push({cell: [111, 222, 333] });

var data = {
    total: 3,    
    page:1,
    rows: rows
}

$('table').flexAddData(data);//.flexReload();
```

but after executing this, it just empties my table.

full and live example [can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/m93qg/2/)

**Notes:**
->I comment the last line which tries to load json object because it empties table.
->In this jsfiddle example I am using link for flexigrid from flexigrid.info website,
which in chrome doesn't work, in firefox it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure it out, in initial creating of flexigrid table,
I am missing to pass

```
dataType : 'json'
```

working copy can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/m93qg/3/