# jquery flexigrid edit array without read database table

Tags: flexigrid

i add content in flexigrid directly
( see at [Flexigrid loading data from local json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664406/flexigrid-loading-data-from-local-json-object) or [Populate Flexigrid with an array or populate it by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209926/populate-flexigrid-with-an-array-or-populate-it-by-code) )

and how can i edit the array that i was pushed in without via << $("#flex1").flexigrid({ url: >> function ?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution by DOM

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/flexigrid/0oRmeJRAnpc

```
function getSelectedRow() {
    var arrReturn        = [];
    $('.trSelected').each(function() {
            var arrRow                = [];
            $(this).find('div').each(function() {
                    arrRow.push( $(this).html() );
            });
            arrReturn.push(arrRow);
    });
    return arrReturn;
```

read as array